# How do I install pip on Arch Linux?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I untarred this: `python-pip-1.5.6-2-any.pkg.tar.xz`

`tar -xf python-pip-1.5.6-2-any.pkg.tar.xz`

And it made a `usr` folder with subfolders `bin`, `lib`, and `share`.

Inside `bin` is `pip`, `pip3`, and `pip3.4`.

How am I supposed to run `makepkg`? How can I install this?

Comment: does get-pip.py not work? https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Answer (score 123):

`pacman -S python-pip` should also work.

The current version in the [repository](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/python-pip/) is 1.5.6-2.

***Note***: for Python 2.7, you would need to install `python2-pip` instead of `python-pip`.

Comment: Note that this can produce the following error: `failed to commit transaction (conflicting files) python-wheel: /usr/bin/wheel exists in filesystem`

Comment: This fails with `error: externally-managed-environment`.

Answer (score 19):

The instruction *[Installation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)* (pip documentation) may work for you.

So basically:

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```