# OpenCV in archlinux/manjaro

Tags: python, linux, opencv, archlinux, manjaro

I've installed Numpy 1.10.4-1 and OpenCV 2.4.12.2-2 on my Manjaro partition.
When I try to import cv2 into a python2.7 script, I get the resulting error.

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so)
>>>
```

I've searched throughout the internet for an answer but I can never get a clear solution to this issue. Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to install opencv 3.1.0? edit: How have you installed your opencv 2.4? perhaps you have linked against c++-6 libraries... i think opencv works currently only with c++-5

Answer (score 3):

Install `pip2` for python2.7

```
pacman -S python2-pip
```

Then using `pip2`, install `opencv-python`

```
sudo pip2 install opencv-python
```

Now you should be able to import `cv2` without a problem.

```
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jun 27 2018, 13:05:28) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180531] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

**Sources**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557686/9215267

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/